# How to add a class to a class with Javascript not JQ

Tags: javascript

trying to figure out how to find a class and add a class to it using javascript. all example online are with id , I need to find the classs. Any idea guys?

I am adding a class once the page is loaded.

```
<nav class="menu custom-effect" id="customMenu">
                    <ul class="menu-list">
                        <li class="menu-item current_page_item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Who we are</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">What we offer</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Our news</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
                      // document.getElementById("current_page_item").classList.add( "current-page");

                      var element = document.getElementById("customMenu");
                      var elementClass = element.getElementsByClassName("current_page_item");
                      elementClass[0].ClassNames.add("extraClass");



                      console.log(element);
                        console.log(elementClass);


                    });
            </script>
```

Comment: Which element are you trying to find and why do you have domcontentloaded event

Comment: I got domcontentloaded because I am adding a class after I load the page, I was trying to find current_page_item and I figured it out how,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you search for a class you get an array I understood and not just one element, so you need to referece the element u want as it picks up all the classes.
the answear to the code is

```
<script>
  var element = document.getElementById("menu-main-menu");
                  var elementClass = element.getElementsByClassName("current_page_item");
                  elementClass[0].classList.add("foo");
</script>
```

classList implementation of these methods is super easy now that I understood the issue:

// adds class "foo" to el

el.classList.add("foo");

// removes class "bar" from el

el.classList.remove("bar");

// toggles the class "foo"

el.classList.toggle("foo");

// outputs "true" to console if el contains "foo", "false" if not

console.log( el.classList.contains("foo") );

// add multiple classes to el

el.classList.add( "foo", "bar" );